# What is causing the HTTP 500 errors on LOCK commands in the Windows Application event log?

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

What is causing the HTTP 500 errors on LOCK commands in the Windows Application event log?

Server is running Windows Server 2016....ITHit.WebDAV.Server.dll v4.0.24.15.0...ITHitWebDAVClient.js v1.9.2.1483...Office on client PCs is Office 365

I tried to include the WebDAVLog.txt but the uploaded failed (multiple times)

IIS Log entry:

```
2019-08-03 11:11:32 8.20.78.22 LOCK /TMS/Edit_WebDAV/MFG-SOP-101.docx - 443 -  Microsoft+Office+Word+2014 - 500 0 0 140
2019-08-03 11:19:03 8.20.78.22 LOCK /TMS/Edit_WebDAV/MFG-SOP-101.docx - 443 -  Microsoft+Office+Word+2014 - 500 0 0 78
```

Windows Application event log error:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 8/3/2019 6:19:02 AM 
Event time (UTC): 8/3/2019 11:19:02 AM 
Event ID: 1711f02c0f5c441d8e5240453de14941 
Event sequence: 68 
Event occurrence: 29 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/TMS-1-132092893366845611 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /TMS 
    Application Path: xxxx\WebRoot\ 
    Machine name: xxxx 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 5240 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at da.i(IHierarchyItem A_0, DavContextBase A_1)
   at da.ProcessRequest(DavContextBase context, IHierarchyItem item)
   at ITHit.WebDAV.Server.DavEngine.Run(DavContextBase context)
   at TMS_WEB.WebDAVServerImpl.DavHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in D:\Projects\TMS_Net_8.0\TMS_Web\WebDAVServerImpl\DavHandler.cs:line 53
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Request information: 
    Request URL: https://xxxxxx:443/TMS/Edit_WebDAV/MFG-SOP-101.docx 
    Request path: /TMS/Edit_WebDAV/MFG-SOP-101.docx 
    User host address: xxxxx 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: xxxxx 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 124 
    Thread account name: xxxxx 
    Is impersonating: True 
    Stack trace:    at da.i(IHierarchyItem A_0, DavContextBase A_1)
   at da.ProcessRequest(DavContextBase context, IHierarchyItem item)
   at ITHit.WebDAV.Server.DavEngine.Run(DavContextBase context)
   at TMS_WEB.WebDAVServerImpl.DavHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in D:\Projects\TMS_Net_8.0\TMS_Web\WebDAVServerImpl\DavHandler.cs:line 53
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Expect not to see any 500 errors on LOCK commands from Office 365 on client PC

Comment: The document (MFP-SOP-101.docx) is 686KB…and the browser is Chrome…

Comment: To find out you need to check line 53 in your DavHandler.cs. If i remember correctly the kind of standard implementation of the old version of ITHit threw errors on missing values or if you send a LOCK request for a Shared lock. But this is implementation specific, so no one can really answer it.